# Analysing program bitshifting

Tags: c, bit-shift

I'll start with the code rightaway:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned char value = 0xAF;
  printf("%02x\n", value);
  value = (value << 4) | (value >> 4);
  printf("%02x\n", value);
  return 0;
}
```

Firstly I thought you can't store numbers in chars and that you would need to make that an int. Appearently not. Then, if I did the bitshifting mats:

```
value << 4 = 101011110
value >> 4 =   1010111 

101011110
| 1010111
=101011111
```

and that would be `0x15f`. 
If I compile that code it prints

```
af
fa
```

Can anyone explain to me where I'm thinking wrong?

Comment: No, I'm analysing this code from former tests (studying for the exam tomorrow) and that always ends up kinda odd if I copy and paste it. But I fixed it now.

Comment: May be you can look into data range for different data types

Comment: Ah, now that I have the answer I got your hint. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the baseline, `0xaf` is `1010-111116` (and we're assuming an eight-bit `char` here based on the code though it's not mandated by the standard).

The expression `value << 4` will left-shift that by *four* bits (not one as you seem to think), giving `1010-1111-000016` and, yes, it's more than an eight-bit `char` because of integer promotions (both operands of a `<<` expression are promoted to `int` as per `ISO C11 6.5.7` and also in earlier iterations of the standard).

The expression `value >> 4` will *right-shift* it by four bits, giving `101016`.

When you `bitwise-or` those together, you get:

```
1010-1111-0000
          1010
==============
1010-1111-1010
```

and when you finally try to shoe-horn that back into the eight-bit `value`, it lops off the upper bits, giving `1111-101016`, which is `0xFA`.

Comment: Thank you really much for that detailled analysis!

Answer (score 4):

Bit shifting 4 shifts 4 binary digits, not 2 as you seem to be showing. It also shifts 1 hex digit. So if you have 0xAF, shifting left 4 gives you 0xF0. Because it is a `char`, it only has 8 bits and the A is cut off. Shifting right 4 similarly yields 0xA. `0x0A | 0xF0 == 0xFA`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't even recognize... But I didn't even think that a char only has 8 bits, thanks for answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You might have messed up the bit representations in your calculation.

Ok. I will try to explain according to the code you have provided.

value 0XAF = 10101111

value << 4 = 11110000

value >> 4 = 00001010

11110000
|00001010 = 11111010 and hence the 0XFA.

Explanation: 
1. Representation is in binary 8 bit.
2. When you left/right shift by a number, I think you are considering it in terms of multiplication and division, but in 8-bit binary representation it just gets shifted by 4 places and the bits get replaced by 0.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

because sizeof(unsigned char) is equal to 1.its a 8bit data.
the range of "value" is from 0x0 to 0xFF, that's the valid bit is from bit0 to bit7.

so when assign 0x15F to "value" after bitshifting, only the data from bit 0 to bit7 are assigned to variable "value", bit8 is cut off.

0x15f ---binarization--->  0001 **0101 1111**

variable "value" is a 8bit data, so, only **0101 1111** is assigned to it.

value ---binarization--->   **0101 1111**